# Cocoa Pods and Google Maps SDK

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, cocoapods

When using CocoaPods to get the Google Maps SDK for iOS, I'm having troubles importing the sdk header file (`#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`).
I'm new to CocoaPods but I think I have everything working fine with the other libraries that I use (RestKit, AFNetworking...). 
For these APIs I still need to import the lib like this `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` instead of just `#import "AFNetworking"`. But it works fine.
For Google Maps SDK I need to import it like this `#import <Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` which leads to a compilation error because in the GoogleMaps.h header the other files are imported like this:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GMSCameraPosition.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GMSCameraUpdate.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GMSCircle.h>
...
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not have to import anything linked with CocoaPods using `<` and `>`. It should simply be `#import "Foo.h"`. In the case of Google Maps based on my test project I just had to use `#import "GoogleMaps.h"` and it imported correctly. Make sure you're installing with the newest version of CocoaPods (`pod --version` currently 0.21.0) otherwise you may need to update it (`[sudo] gem update`). Also make sure you're opening the created `xcworkspace` file instead of the `xcodeproject`

Comment: On the CocoaPods home page, there is this line `#import <Reachability.h>`. I'm running the 0.21.0 version of CocoaPods. If I try to import with simple quotes nothing gets completed. Also the targets libPods-FRAMEWORK.a are all red as if they were never built. Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't auto complete but it should link anyways.

Comment: Today I updated CocoaPods to the 0.22.1 version. And everything works fine. I run pod install again after the update and now I can import the file like you said. So thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue(and am using cocoapods), specifically where the error "GoogleMaps.h" file not found. My solution(if the above fails to work), is that your Pods' Target Support Files fail to include the correct header path for "GoogleMaps.h".

**Step #1**

If you examine your project directory in Finder, click on Pods directory, then Public directory, then GoogleMaps directory, you'll notice that there is a **second** GoogleMaps directory. Inside that second GoogleMaps directory contains the header files pertaining to the GoogleMaps pod. Now time to check that Pods target support files have this path as the header path for GoogleMaps.

**Step #2**

Close Xcode Project. Go to the parent directory of your project. For me, it's my home directory, which can be reached at `cd ~`. Traverse into your Pods' Target support files:

```
cd ~/{your_project_name}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods
```

Then open up your Pods.debug.xcconfig file in your favorite editor:

```
vi Pods.debug.xcconfig
```

Edit the line

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps"
```

with the new header path

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps"
```

Leave the rest of the Pods.debug.xcconfig **untouched**. Follow this same process for Pods.release.xcconfig.

**Step #3**

Re-open your .xcworkspace file. Clean your project(cmd-shift-k) and then re-build(cmd-b).

Comment: In my case (at least) it is `Pods/Header/Public`, not `Pods/Public`.