# Can't get GoogleMaps SDK to work on Xcode Test Target (works on App Target)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, xctest

#### The Setup

I have successfully integrated the GoogleMaps SDK into my Swift 2 project using CocoaPods.

My setup is pretty much that suggested by the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial) on the subject.
The only difference I can find is, I have to add this line to AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps // <- THIS LINE

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    ...
```

...in order to use the framework's classes. The tutorial suggests importing:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

...to the bridging header instead.

The app works without problems.

---

#### The Problem:

When I tried to run the test target auto-generated by Xcode, I get the error:

> No such module 'GoogleMaps'

...pointing at the to the swift import statement in AppDelegate above.

So, I decide to switch to the way it is in the tutorial instead: I comment out the line `import GoogleMaps` in AppDelegate.swift and add an Objective-C-style import statement to the bridging header.

***However***, I can not get it right:

1. If I use: `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` or `#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"`, it gives me:

   > Use of unresolved identifier 'GMServices'

   at AppDelegate.swift when building the app target.
2. If I use: `#import "GoogleMaps.h"`, it gives me:

   > 'GoogleMaps.h': file not found

   at the bridging header.

I have tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463974/433373), but the results are (puzzlingly) the same...?

---

Next, I checked the value of `Build Settings / Search Paths / Framework Search Paths` for both targets (app and tests). The app target had the entry:

`"${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Frameworks"`

...which the test target lacked, so I added it, and reverted to the swift-style import (the only one that works at least when building the app target), but I still get:

```
import GoogleMaps   <! No such module 'GoogleMaps'
```

**How can I run tests for my app??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out all I had to do is fix the Podfile (and run `pod install`), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077217/433373).

My old pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

def import_pods
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

workspace 'MyWorkspace'
xcodeproj 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'

target : MyApp do
    xcodeproj 'MyApp MyApp.xcodeproj'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

My current pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

def import_pods
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

workspace 'MyWorkspace'
xcodeproj 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'

target 'MyApp', :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    import_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests', :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    import_pods
end
```