# Adding API key to an application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on GoogleMaps APIs and am following this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start .I have successfully completed the 4th step and now am facing problem in the next step where i have to import GoogleMaps in App Delegate's .m file. But i m unable to do so. Can anyone tell me why??

[image]

Comment: Have you reopened the project using "project.xcworkspace" after adding cocoapod?...

Comment: yes i did reopen the project.

Comment: You have to import the folder name in pods folder. Try import GoogleMaps. Also You will have to add GoogleMaps.bundle to your bundle.

Comment: can you explain in detail  please!!

Comment: In Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Add GoogleMaps.bundle and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are in the correct way , just add the following code

**@import GoogleMaps;** in your header file or use like `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"xxxxxxx"];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

> While you should be able to start using the **Google Maps SDK** at this stage, there is one more step you need to take because of a **bug** in **Cocoapods**. In the **Project Navigator**, select the **yourPRojectName** project at the top. Choose the **yourPRojectName** target, select the **Build Settings** tab, and in **Other Linker Flags** add **-ObjC** as shown below:

[image]

Comment: the header file "Google" is not showing while importing. Do i have to add in Link Binary in Libraries in Build Phases???

Comment: sorry by mistake i have written Google...i meant "GoogleMaps" only

Comment: clean and run once

Comment: done but still showing Module 'GoogleMaps' not found :(

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451837/cant-get-googlemaps-sdk-to-work-on-xcode-test-target-works-on-app-target

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is the issue with pods. 
Make sure you have completely installed googleMaps pod.
Please try to build application before import. It solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed pod files properly. You can verify it by checking whether all header files are present under "Pods" in "Project navigator" tab at left side.
[image]

After that build your app and import

```
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
```

Comment: All header files are there i have checked sir....but still am unable to import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h". How is that possible??

Comment: once try cleaning your project and then rebuild it